# New version of doing a for loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I understand there is now a new way to write `for` loops using `foreach`? I am using **c#** and **Visual Studio 2015**.

Here is the current loop:

```
for(int iCodeLength = 4; iCodeLength >= 1; iCodeLength--)
{
    if(xmlGenioCodes.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("GenioCodes[Code =\"{0}\"]", strCodeMX.Substring(0, iCodeLength))) != null)
    {
        strCodeMXLayer = strCodeMX.Substring(0, iCodeLength);
        break;
    }
}
```

What is the new way I can write the same `for` loop definition using `foreach`? And could you direct me to a good webpage that explains it as I not know what to search for.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you want to use `foreach`?

Comment: I have flagged your question as being of extremely low-quality. You need to be more specific with regards to what type of loop you're looking for. Are you hoping to make use of C#'s LINQ language features? Do you want to use a `foreach` loop? Your question is too unclear to answer at the moment.

Comment: @DanForbes I am sorry it was unclear. I beleive what I am asking for is foreach.

Comment: No need to apologize; I'm not trying to chide you. I just want to make sure you understand why your question is being down-voted so that you can have a chance to edit and improve it. If you do so, I will gladly remove my down-vote.

Comment: Thanks. :) I get a little demoralized when my questions are shot down without any kind explanation. You provided this. :) I have edited the question.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Just so you know there are a couple of other things that could be prompting the down-votes. The first is that `foreach` is really not a new language construct, it has been around for many years now. The other is that you edited your question to specifically reference `foreach` it seems that what you are asking for is a tutorial on how to use `foreach`, which is something you should really just google for since that isn't what SO is really for. The last is that your example code is actually a situation where `foreach` is not well suited, so it would be strange to rewrite it

Comment: @KevinWells The truth is that I dedit my question because I was told I was vague. The point was I did not kwow what the alternatives were and I was anticipating a simple list of what they were. Not to worry. But thank you anyway.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle That's fine, and I don't think this is that bad of a question, I just wanted to provide some outside perspective on why it might be garnering the down-votes it has gotten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this loop is a good candidate for a `foreach` loop. If you were to do so, it would look something like this:

```
var codeLengths = new[] { 4, 3, 2, 1 };
foreach (length in codeLengths)
{
    if(xmlGenioCodes.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("GenioCodes[Code =\"{0}\"]", strCodeMX.Substring(0, length))) != null)
    {
        strCodeMXLayer = strCodeMX.Substring(0, length);
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT

Per the request in your question, [here is a link where you can find more information about C#'s `foreach` language feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Thank you for this. I can see it would not be a good candidate, but you have taught be the concept now and where to find more information. Thank you.

Comment: You should look into LINQ too...it is, in a word, awesome. If you have some extra cash, you should invest in [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)...it is a wonderful tool. Although some might criticize it as a lazy choice (since it "automagically" fixes your code for you), it has been quite a valuable learning tool for me. I have incorporated most of ReSharper's suggestions into my natural coding style and have learned how to use many advanced features of the C# language through my use of the ReSharper tool.

Comment: I have never heard of LINQ.

Comment: You will never be able to say that again, @AndrewTruckle! I think I've done enough googling for you today, so if you'd like to learn more about LINQ, I would encourage you to poke around on MSDN and in Visual Studio.